# node server.js not responding

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I'm pretty new to node and I'm trying to create a simple server for my website but when I type in node `server.js` in command prompt nothing happens.

```
var http = require("http");  
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
       response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
       response.write("It's alive!");
       response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

This is what I see when I try to run my `server.js` file:

[image]

I'm fairly certain my code is right, is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Comment: how long did you wait? looks to me like there is no error there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The server is working just fine. You need to visit `http://localhost:3000/` from your browser to view the expected output ("It's alive!").

To write messages to the console, use `console.log()`.

Comment: Also, adding `console.log('server listening on port 3000')` right after the `listen()` call is a nice way to remind yourself that the program worked and is functioning normally.

Comment: I did this, I cant even see anything on the console. I am in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

The console output you show seems correct given your code.

Did you open a webbrowser and try opening ***http://localhost:3000***?

If you want to see some console output to confirm your server started up, try adding this at the end of your *server.js* file:

```
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:3000');
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to hit the URL ***http://localhost:3000***.

The server is already started after you hit the command **"node server.js"** and you will get the output - "*It's alive!*" because of this line present in your code: `response.write("It's alive!");`

Answer (score -1):

First time starting up node server made a very small mistake of not calling "response.end" as a function that made the server not response and take very long to load. Should have been response.end()

```
const server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
response.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
response.write('Hello Node')
response.end 
})
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30801112)

Comment: The code in the question shows that the OP **is** calling `response.end()`.

Answer (score -1):

Change the port to 5000, and then go to `http://localhost:5000/`. There may be other service running on `localhost:3000`.

Comment: If there was something running on port 3000 already, then the server would output an error message and quit when the OP tried to run it. We can see that doesn't happen.

Comment: Note also that back in 2015 someone wrote an answer that the OP has accepted as correct.